# How to upgrade from an interim release after the maintenance period is over?

Tags: upgrade, 21.10

I have come back to a computer that hadn't been switched on since March 2022 (1 year), it has Ubuntu 21.10 installed and I'm having difficulty upgrading it to 22.04.

I know 21.10 was an interim release and I'm guessing it's 9 month maintenance period is over.

I have tried both:

```
sudo apt update
and 
sudo apt upgrade
```

I'm not too surprised the update doesn't work but I'm a little disappointed if this is what is preventing me from doing an upgrade.

Is there a way to upgrade without doing a fresh install ?

I found a page that attempts to help but it was written more than 12 years ago:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades#SpecificOlder

These are the errors I get:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libfwupdplugin5
The following packages will be upgraded:
  fwupd fwupd-signed libfwupd2 linux-firmware
4 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 201 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,808 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 fwupd-signed amd64 1.42~ubuntu21.10.2+1.2-2~21.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libfwupd2 amd64 1.7.5-3~21.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libfwupdplugin5 amd64 1.7.5-3~21.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Err:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 fwupd amd64 1.7.5-3~21.10.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Ign:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 1.201.5
Err:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 linux-firmware all 1.201.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fwupd-signed/fwupd-signed_1.42%7eubuntu21.10.2%2b1.2-2%7e21.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fwupd/libfwupd2_1.7.5-3%7e21.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fwupd/libfwupdplugin5_1.7.5-3%7e21.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fwupd/fwupd_1.7.5-3%7e21.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.201.5_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

//////

I got pointed at this answer which is perfect:
[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: You can always try https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/231142  I realize that it was written a long time ago, but it still should work today to help upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: have you tried sudo apt-get update ?

Comment: The page you reference was last updated 2022-08-20 which wasn't more than 12 years ago; do you expect documentation to be re-written instead of edited/updated?   Release-upgrade instructions are provided for every release (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades which covers 21.10 to 22.04) however the assumption is you do it before EOL is reached.  The page you provided tells you how to fix the issue; ie. read "*Update sources.list*" and remove your country code (gb.) as mirrors drop support for EOL releases so you must switch to the main archive.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, the answer given at https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release was pretty straight forward and it worked perfectly